# CSV multi calling csv.DictReader(f) to find the data but shows unexcepted keywords in result

Tags: python, csv

I am a new csv beginners, when i calling value `key=csv.DictReader(f)` to my scripts it shows the different result.

my csv file:

```
Date,Max_Temp,Mean_Temp

2010/2/4,12,7

2010/2/5,9,6

2010/2/6,10,7
```

my codes:

```
filename='sitka_weather_2014.csv'
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    '''DictReader for the firstline as the key'''
    key=csv.DictReader(f)
    print([row['Date'] for row in key])
    f.seek(0)
    print([(row['Date']) for row in key])
```

Then it shows the different results:

for the first print result:`[2010/2/4,2010/2/5,2010/2/6]`

for the 2rd print result:`[Date,2010/2/4,2010/2/5,2010/2/6]`

**What cause the 2rd output result including the keywords`Date`????**

if i use`print([(row['Date']) for row in csv.DictReader(f) ])` to instead of using value `key`it show the correct result, but i dont know why, it really confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key=csv.DictReader(f)` reads the first line of the file to determine the dictionary key names from the header row.

When you rewind the file with `f.seek(0)`, `key` (the `DictReader`) is initialized and has already determined its keys.  The next row read from `key` is the first line of the file, the header row, but it is treated as data.

When you use `print([(row['Date']) for row in csv.DictReader(f)])` a new `DictReader` is created that reads the first row for the keys again, so it works normally.

Reading the file twice is inefficient, but you can create a new `DictReader` to trigger reading the header again, or read the first line yourself to skip the headers if you must.

```py
import csv

# Use newline='' per csv module docs
with open('sitka_weather_2014.csv',newline='') as f:
    key=csv.DictReader(f)
    print([row['Date'] for row in key])

    f.seek(0)
    key = csv.DictReader(f) # re-init
    # f.readline()          # or use this
    print([(row['Date']) for row in key])
```

Output:

```
['2010/2/4', '2010/2/5', '2010/2/6']
['2010/2/4', '2010/2/5', '2010/2/6']
```

If the dataset isn't enormous, just read the data into memory instead of reading the file twice.

```py
import csv

with open('sitka_weather_2014.csv','r',newline='') as f:
    dict_reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    data = list(dict_reader)

print([row['Date'] for row in data])
print([row['Date'] for row in data])
```